# How to properly dual boot kubuntu and windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, kubuntu, windows-10

Originally i was using only windows 10 on one of my computers ssds and yesterday i installed linux on my other ssd. After linux was successfully installed i was no longer able to boot into windows 10 from the other drive. It kept sending me to grub rescue, but i was able to boot into linux just fine. I tried many different commands in linux to try and fix the problem but no matter what i tried grub couldnt see windows. I am now restoring windows from a back up and would like to know what should i do to not encounter this problem again and easily switch between kubuntu and windows when ever i please?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Install both in Legacy mode as opposed to EFI mode. Some may disagree, but trust me, it will make your life *so* much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You should check some Windows configurations before proceed to install Kubuntu.

Fast Startup locks down the hard drive so once you power off access to the disk from anothe OS is not posible (http://www.howtogeek.com/243901/the-pros-and-cons-of-windows-10s-fast-startup-mode/).

Also this could be a problem with uefi ([Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)), make sure your bios is in CSM Boot mode.